# Limits on a parameter $\alpha$ to get positive definite matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Given positive semi-definite $n\times n$ matrices $B_k$, how would I go about getting the limits on $\alpha_k$ such that the expression
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{I}-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\alpha_kB_k
\end{equation}
is a positive definite matrix?
In the expression above, there are $m-1$ matrices (the $B_k$ 's), all positive semi-definite. Also, there is a condition on $\alpha_k$ that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\alpha_k<1,\quad \alpha_k>0
\end{equation}

Comment: You can drop your condition, which just says $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\alpha_k\le1$ (supposing you want $\alpha_k\ge0$). So you may as well write $\mathbb{I}-\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_kB_k
$, with  condition $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\alpha_k\le1$.